# SQL Server 2012 Installation Error on Windows 2008 Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-server

I am facing an error while trying to install SQL Server 2012 EXPRESS ADVANCED EDITION(32bit) on Windows Server 2008 Enterprise(64bit).

After passing Rule Check, at install updates section, error occurs about update could not be downloaded. On clicking next, following error in dialog box occurs.

```
SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error:

Setup encountered a failure while running job UpdateResult.

Error code 0x876E0003.
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You should install the 64 bit version.

Comment: @MaxVernon Is the error occured because of 32bit?

Comment: @Hemal. Installing 32 bit SQL Server on 64 bit windows is supported so no issue with that. Have you read [Hardware and software requirements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506%28v=sql.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) before installing. It seems that you are trying to install SP/update with original installable. Please dont do that. Use [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/petersad/archive/2011/07/13/product-update-in-sql-server-code-named-denali.aspx) to make `UpdateEnabled=False` and then again run the installation

Comment: @Shanky I tried installing with the link you provided and used `Setup.exe /UpdateEnabled=FALSE`. Still no luck.

Comment: You are very quick. How about .net frameworks ? Did you read the requirements and made sure you meet all of them

Comment: I have installed .NET 4.5 on the server, and also its Windows Server 2008 Enterprise SP2. .NET 3 is enabled from Add Features wizard. How do i Know if OS is R2 or not?

Comment: Ok, I solved this problem by installing SP1 for .NET 3.5, SP1 was needed. Thanks @Shanky

Comment: Now, at the middle of the installation, `The Windows Installer Service could not be accessed` error occurs. Though installation finished, but Management Tools and Reporting Services are not installed.

Comment: Add summary.txt file into the question

Answer (score -1):

Please include the option "**UpdateEnabled=False**" in the **defaultsetup.ini** file which can be found in Media**X64\defaultsetup.ini**. 
This works like a charm. Please let us know how this goes.

Comment: OP stated in comments that UpdateEnabled=FALSE didn't work. Can you clarify why you think your answer is different or better?